# Gatling - Session EL does not get recognised inside header

Tags: scala, chain, gatling

I am trying to separate the chain and keep it in a re-usable variable

```
package computerdatabase

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.jsonpath._

class Test1 extends Simulation {

  //Global Users
  val userMap = scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap[String, String]()
  //Randomiser 
  val rnd = new scala.util.Random
  val httpConf = http
    .baseURL("http://demo1263864.mockable.io/") // Here is the root for all relative URLs
    .acceptHeader("application/json") // Here are the common headers
    .doNotTrackHeader("1")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0")

  val headers_1 = scala.collection.mutable.Map("Content-Type" -> "application/json")

  val chain1 = exec(
      http("chain request ")
        .post("gatling1")
        .headers((headers_1 += "pList" -> "${pList}").toMap)
        .body(StringBody("""{"${pList}"}"""))
        .check(status.is(404)))

  val scn = scenario("Simple request")
    .exec(
      http("If request ")
        .get("gatling1")
        .headers(headers_1.toMap)
        .check(jsonPath("$.result").is("SUCCESS"),
          jsonPath("$.data[*]").ofType[Map[String, Any]].findAll.saveAs("pList")))
    .exec(chain1)

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpConf))
}
```

This compiles fine but during runtime gives me following error

> 16:35:25.156 [INFO ] i.g.h.c.HttpProtocol - Start warm up
>
> 16:35:25.681 [INFO ] i.g.h.c.HttpProtocol - Warm up done
>
> 16:35:25.731 [ERROR] i.g.h.a.HttpRequestAction - No attribute named
>   'pList' is defined
>
> 16:35:25.732 [ERROR] i.g.h.a.HttpRequestAction - No attribute named
>   'pList' is defined

It does not gives any line number but I am sure its the following line which  has a problem.

```
.headers((headers_1 += "pList" -> "${pList}").toMap)
```

When I use chain1 inline in the exec , it works fine.

[Cross-posted](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/ajv-jmvJ6EY) from Gatling User Group